# MySQL: Getting the most recent action per row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to write a query where I'd like to get a list of users's last "special actions", so I have these tables:

```
table_users
id     username     email          etc.
1      moloc        a@mail.com     etc.
2      lilly        b@mail.com     etc.
3      sammm        c@mail.com     etc.


table_special_actions
id     user_id      action_id      date
1      3            25             2010-11-01 22:51:56
2      3            37             2010-11-02 18:09:33
3      3            265            2010-11-03 07:20:12


table_actions
id        action
1         Open a secret
2         Level up
3         Open magic door
etc.      etc.
```

My objective is to get an user list where I have only the last special action for each one, so I've thought something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_users AS users
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, action_id, MAX(date) AS action_date
    FROM table_special_actions
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY action_date
) s_actions
ON s_actions.user_id = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN table_actions AS actions
ON s_actions.action_id = actions.id
```

This doesn't work properly because it's return this:

```
-----users-----    ------------s_actions------------    -----actions-----
id     username    action_id     date                   action
3      sammm       25            2010-11-03 07:20:12    Action linked to action_id 25
```

I've expected to get this:

```
-----users-----    ------------s_actions------------    -----actions-----
id     username    action_id     date                   action
3      sammm       265           2010-11-03 07:20:12    Action linked to action_id 265
```

The strange thing is the action_id, I always get the last date and this is ok, but I've also always get the fist action_id instead of the one relative to the correct date row.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: change action_id, max(date) to max(action_id) as action_id, max(date) as action_date and pls dont use reserved words as fieldnames - arghh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. Try:

```
SELECT *
    FROM table_users AS users
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, MAX(date) AS MaxDate
                       FROM table_special_actions
                       GROUP BY user_id) s_actions
            ON s_actions.user_id = users.user_id
        LEFT JOIN table_special_actions s2_actions
            ON s_actions.userid = s2_actions.id
                AND s_actions.MaxDate = s2_actions.date
        LEFT JOIN table_actions AS actions
            ON s2_actions.action_id = actions.id
```

Comment: thank you, you've solved a problem It's making troubles to me by two days with a simple and linear solution.

Answer (score 0):

You got this result probably because you used an aggregate function (`MAX`) and grouped only by the first column (`user_id`) and left the second column (`action_id`) out of grouping and aggregation.